# Google sheets to excel formula conversion

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

the current formula working on excel to populate an array of cells based on a drop down selection from a separate 'data' sheet

```
=ifna(filter(Data!A2:H13, Data!A1:H1 = C17))
```

When converted to excel is giving this formula

```
=IFERROR(@__xludf.DUMMYFUNCTION("ifna(filter(Data!A2:H13, Data!A1:H1 = C17))"),"Fruit and Waffles")
```

Can anyone please help me understand the correct conversion. or alternatively help with what the formula should look like on Excel

I have tried the original formula in Excel but not working. The drop down selection does not change the cells

Comment: Remove `IFNA()` and use `IFERROR()` --> `=IFERROR(FILTER(Data!A2:H13, Data!A1:H1 = C17),"Fruit and Waffles")`

Answer (score 0):

The fact is `Google Sheets` Formulas are not compatible with `Excel` desktop or web applications, hence why it adds an extra such combination with `@__xludf.DUMMYFUNCTION` and the present static value returned by and `IFEEROR()`. To avoid errors in Excel one could use the following by excluding the `IFNA()` and use `IFERROR()` function as a whole to return a value when an error is encountered.

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(Data!A2:H13, Data!A1:H1 = C17),"Fruit and Waffles")
```

---

Also, `FILTER()` function has its own if not found argument i.e the last parameter --> `[if_empty]` enclosed within square brackets which means its an optional parameter. That said, one could amend the formula as

```
=FILTER(Data!A2:H13, Data!A1:H1 = C17,"Fruit and Waffles")
```

---